# it is possible to get my android contact (caller id or caller name) by using bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want o connect my Bluetooth device with my android phone and get caller id(Phone name) or caller name.this contact saved my phone and otherwise get phone number.

Comment: I guess It is possible as many bluetooth devices shows called name or contact on device as user gets call!

Comment: How to possible? i mean any have you tutorial any reference...